# Apache Flink: LEFT JOIN with a TableFunction does not return expected result

Tags: left-join, apache-flink, flink-sql

Flink version: 1.3.1

I created two tables, one is from memory, another is from UDTF. When I tested join and left join, they returned the same result. What I expected was left join had more rows than join.

My test code is this:

```
public class ExerciseUDF {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            test_3();
        }
        public static void test_3() throws Exception {
                // 1. set up execution environment
                ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
                BatchTableEnvironment tEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env);

                DataSet<WC> input = env.fromElements(
                        new WC("Hello", 1),
                        new WC("Ciao", 1),
                        new WC("Hello", 1));

                // 2. register the DataSet as table "WordCount"
                tEnv.registerDataSet("WordCount", input, "word, frequency");

                Table table;
                DataSet<WC> result;
                        DataSet<WCUpper> resultUpper;
                table = tEnv.scan("WordCount");
                // 3. table left join user defined table
                System.out.println("table left join user defined table");
                tEnv.registerFunction("myTableUpperFunc",new MyTableFunc_2());
                table = tEnv.sql("SELECT S.word as word, S.frequency as frequency, S.word as myupper FROM WordCount as S left join LATERAL TABLE(myTableUpperFunc(S.word)) as T(word,myupper) on S.word = T.word");
                resultUpper = tEnv.toDataSet(table, WCUpper.class);
                resultUpper.print(); // out put —— WCUpper Ciao 1 CIAO, however, without the row having Hello

                // 4. table join user defined table
                System.out.println("table join user defined table");
                tEnv.registerFunction("myTableUpperFunc",new MyTableFunc_2());
                table = tEnv.scan("WordCount");
                table = tEnv.sql("SELECT S.word as word, S.frequency as frequency, T.myupper as myupper FROM WordCount as S join LATERAL TABLE(myTableUpperFunc(S.word)) as T(word,myupper) on S.word = T.word"
                );
                resultUpper = tEnv.toDataSet(table, WCUpper.class);
                resultUpper.print();
            }

            public static class WC {
                public String word;
                public long frequency;

                // public constructor to make it a Flink POJO
                public WC() {
                }

                public WC(String word, long frequency) {
                    this.word = word;
                    this.frequency = frequency;
                }

                @Override
                public String toString() {
                    return "WC " + word + " " + frequency;
                }
            }


            // user defined table function
            public static class MyTableFunc_2 extends TableFunction<Tuple2<String,String>>{
                public void eval(String str){ // hello --> hello HELLO
                    System.out.println("upper func executed for "+str);
                    if(str.equals("Hello")){
                        return;
                    }
                    collect(new Tuple2<String,String>(str,str.toUpperCase()));
                    // collect(new Tuple2<String,String>(str,str.toUpperCase()));
                }
            }
    }
```

The output of the left join and join queries are the same. In both cases only one row is returned.

WCUpper Ciao 1 CIAO

However, I think that the left join query should preserve the 'Hello' rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

This is a bug in the translation of TableFunction outer joins with predicates and needs to be fixed.

Thanks, Fabian

Comment: I want to know which rows are matched and not matched between `S` and `T`. Such result seems can't be reached by simply using `ON TRUE` condition. Is there any way to do this? Besides, mysql behaves differently in join ... on ..., a `'Hello'` row will still be returned although join is failed, in this condition some columns may be `null` 
 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html     _If there is a row in A that matches the WHERE clause, but there is no row in B that matches the ON condition, an extra B row is generated with all columns set to NULL._

Comment: Thanks! I looked into this again and you are right. TableFunction outer joins with predicates are broken. I have created a JIRA issue (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7730) and will update my answer. In general it's a good idea to directly reach out to the Flink community if you think you found a bug. Such reports get easily lost on StackOverflow. Thanks!